# How to block access to certain pages to Users who are neither ADMIN nor STAFF in my case in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, middleware

I would like to know:

1 - How to create two different middlewares (for `ADMIN` and `STAFF`) from `SESSION` variables to use them later **to prevent users who are neither ADMIN nor STAFF from accessing pages I don't want that they have access ???**

*Here's what I did, but I'm completely unsure and stuck:*

**FUNCTION PROCESSING ACCESS FOR `ADMIN` MEMBERS:**

```
function checkAdmin()
{
    $_SESSION['hlbank_admin_user'] = array('name' => 'Admin');
    // if the session id is not set, redirect to login page
    if (!isset($_SESSION['hlbank_admin_user'])) {
        header('Location: ' . WEB_ROOT . 'admin/login.php');
        exit;
    }
 
    // the user want to logout
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        doLogout();
    }
}
```

**FUNCTION PROCESSING ACCESS FOR `STAFF` MEMBERS:**

```
function checkStaff()
{
    // if the session id is not set, redirect to login page
    if(strlen($_SESSION['staff_id'])==0) {
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extra= WEB_ROOT . "admin/pages_staff_index.php";
        $_SESSION["staff_id"]="";
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    }
 
    // the user want to logout
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        doLogout();
    }
}
```

- So please help me to correct my two functions above which aim to
  check via THE `SESSION` if the connected User is an `ADMIN` and a
  `STAFF`.
- **How to use both functions at the same time in a Page to check if the
  User is an ADMIN or a STAFF and thus block access to users who are
  neither `ADMIN` nor `STAFF` ???**

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to implement this but here's one. I'd simplify the functions so that they each return a boolean. Move all the redirect logic, logout stuff into the calling code.

I am not sure the name of the session keys you use so I just used `hlbank_admin_user` and `staff_id`. I also made the assumption that if they're set, then the user is that role.

I renamed the functions to `isAdmin` and `isStaff`.

```
function isAdmin(): bool
{
    return isset($_SESSION['hlbank_admin_user']);
}

function isStaff(): bool
{
    return isset($_SESSION['staff_id']);
}
```

Then, in your calling code, you can check for either one.

```
if (!isAdmin() && !isStaff()) {
    // Not authorized >> redirect
}
```

Taking it one step further, you can create a single function to check if they are either an admin or staff.

```
function isPrivileged(): bool
{
    return isAdmin() || isStaff();
}
```

Then, in your calling code, you can check for that.

```
if (!isPrivileged()) {
    // Not authorized >> redirect
}
```

> Thank you for your reply. But I'm confused by your answer. Actually,
> what I don't understand is why you didn't first declare the session
> variables $_SESSION['hlbank_admin_user'] and $_SESSION['staff_id']
> returned in the isAdmin() functions and isStaff() because you just
> returned them with isset in each of those two functions ???
>
> But why return them knowing that they have not yet declared???

Just to clear up any confusion, the way this normally works is during log-in, you set some session variables that you want to track in future requests. You don't need to redeclare them at all in the future. You can simply check for them, or read them.

Pseudocode for log in,

```
session_start()
 
if (username & password = true) {
    // These sessions values will persist for the entire session.
    // Just make sure to call `session_start()` on every page before trying to access them
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
    $_SESSION['role'] = admin;
}
```

Then, when they try to access a restricted page you simply check if they are logged in and of a specific role.

Pseudocode to check access,

```
session_start()

$loggedIn = $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] ?? false;
$role = $_SESSION['role'] ?? '';

if ($isLoggedIn === true && $role === 'admin') {
    // You are logged in and an admin
}
```

Comment: and to check for either or 

```if(! isAdmin()) { // not an admin user redirect to staff area }```

staff area 
```
 if(! isStaff() && ! isAdmin()) { // redirect to login assuming admin access staff area too }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. But I'm confused by your answer. Actually, what I don't understand is why you didn't first declare the session variables `$_SESSION['hlbank_admin_user']` and `$_SESSION['staff_id']` returned in the `isAdmin()` functions and `isStaff()` because you just returned them with `isset` in each of those two functions ???

But why return them knowing that they have not yet declared???

Comment: Because those session variables _should be_ set during log in already. As long as you call `session_start()` on every page, those session variables will persist through requests and you can simply check if they exist. If they don't exist, then by definition the user is not an admin or staff.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer.